# How I have to configure hdfs and pig

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I have a program with pig embeded  in java. I execute pig server in mode local. But when I execute my code I have a execution error. I don¡t know that mean this error.

The java code is :

```
 try {
        System.out.println("principio de carga estadisticas");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("fs.default.name","hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020");
        //System.out.println("cargar estadisticas paso1");
        props.setProperty("mapred.job.tracker","localhost.localdomain:8021");
        System.out.println("cargar estadisticas paso 11 jjjj");
        PigServer pigServer = new PigServer("local");
```

The wrong sentence is

```
    PigServer pigServer = new PigServer("local");
```

The exception is:

```
principio de carga estadisticas
cargar estadisticas paso 11 jjjj
14/07/21 15:25:50 WARN conf.Configuration: fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use     fs.defaultFS
14/07/21 15:25:50 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead,    use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
14/07/21 15:25:50 INFO executionengine.HExecutionEngine: Connecting to hadoop file   system at: file:///
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem    FileSystem implementation
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getScheme(FileSystem.java:207)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2276)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2286)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2303)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:87)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2342)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2324)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:351)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:163)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.init(HDataStorage.java:72)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.<init>(HDataStorage.java:58)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.init(HExecutionEngine.java:204)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.init(HExecutionEngine.java:117)
at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.connect(PigContext.java:240)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:215)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:200)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:196)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:192)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:182)
at bicing.pig.PigEstadisticas.cargarEstadisticas(PigEstadisticas.java:72)
at bicing.hbase.Generadortabla.cargarXML(Generadortabla.java:238)
at bicing.hbase.Generadortabla.main(Generadortabla.java:398)
```

Do I have wrong jar?. How I have to configure hdfs or pig?

Comment: Though I can't be sure, as I too am new to all this, I believe the value for the `PigServer` should be `","`.

Comment: In what mode do you want to run Pig? `new PigServer("local")` will run Pig in local mode. But in Properties you set values for JobTracker and HDFS which used in MapReduce mode. And you does not pass the properties to PigServer constructor. If you want to connect to the cluster, try to create PigServer like this: `new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE, props)`

Comment: The execution error message is 14/07/22 11:07:59 INFO executionengine.HExecutionEngine: Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation